# ActionListener not working Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

What am I missing here?

```
 public class abc extends JFrame    {
 private JButton save = new JButton("Save");

 public abc() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    save.addActionListener(new SaveL());
    p.add(save);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    cp.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }


 }

 class SaveL implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            System.out.println("Hello"); // nothing happens

        }
}
```

Why doesn't my ActionListener work here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `JPanel`, adding your `JButton` to it, then creating a new `JPanel` and adding that panel to your `JFrame`. You need to be adding the original panel to your content pane.

Comment: Thanks. I have adapted my program from here and have exactly the sample thing that its been done here. I'm just chainging the action performed method of the SaveL defined here. How is the program working here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm

Comment: @Ankur That program creates a new `JPanel`, adds stuff to it, adds it to the content pane and then creates a new `JPanel`. You may wish to follow the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to learn the basics.

Comment: My code is exactly the same except I have System.out.println in ActionPerformed on SaveL class in the above link. Why doesn't that work

Comment: @Ankur Your code is not exactly the same. In order for `actionPerformed` to be called, the `Component` your listener is attached to has to generate an `ActionEvent`. `JButton`s generate events when they are clicked. Since you are never adding your `JButton` to your `JFrame`, you cannot generate an `ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is completely messed up. You instantiate your JPanel p twice, your button is declared "open" but is actually "save". You mix GridLayout with BorderLayour constraints. The following code works:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class abc extends JFrame {
    private JButton save = new JButton("Save");

    public abc() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        save.addActionListener(new SaveL());
        p.add(save);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc abc = new abc();
        abc.pack();
        abc.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class SaveL implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello"); // nothing happens

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is re-creating the panel. It's losing the button.

I changed it to:

```
public class abc extends JFrame{   
    private JButton save = new JButton("Save");

    public abc() {
       JPanel p = new JPanel();
       save.addActionListener(new SaveL());
       p.add(save);
       Container cp = getContentPane();

       cp.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     }


}

class SaveL implements ActionListener {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
           System.out.println("Hello"); // nothing happens

       }
}
```

and it worked

Comment: Thanks. I have adapted my program from here and have exactly the sample thing that its been done here. I'm just chainging the action performed method of the SaveL defined here. How is the program working here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm

Comment: @Ankur, i'm sorry but i do not understand what you mean in your comment

Comment: My code is exactly the same except I have System.out.println in ActionPerformed on SaveL class in the above link. Why doesn't that work

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in that page and changed the actionPerformed of SaveL class, it worked with no problem.

what IDE are you using? i think sometimes you cannot see console output in Eclipse (I know i had this problem once).
I did my test on Eclipse, by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
private JButton open = new JButton("Save");

save.addActionListener(new SaveL());
```

Did u declare your save as open?

Comment: No I haven't. That was a copy/paste mistake here. I updated my code. I don't get any errors in my program. Nothing gets displayed in console.